# Algorithm to find non-blocking area/lines

Tags: algorithm, 2d

Diagram:

[image]

What algorithm I can look for to find non-blocking lines?

For example:

```
Input:
Red dot = [x=100, y=200]
Blue lines = [x1=300, y1=100, x2=300, y2=300], [x1=400, y1=0, x2=400, y2=400]
```

Output:

```
Green lines, which is visible from the red dot.
```

Comment: not necessary. x1, y1, x2, y2 can be any number.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ray tracing. You'll only need a simplified version to get the intersections of rays started from the view point to the first obstacle.